# Anchor tag self closed when evaluate html by xpath

Tags: java, html, xpath

I have larger HTML and I **scraped** one div tag using org.dom4j.XPath evaluate method

E.g.:

```
<div class=\"banner\" id=\"banner\">
    <a onclick=\"set_cookie('Books-of-the-month_shop-now_imagetext');\" href=\"/b/books-of-the-month/_/N-2trn\" class=\"bannerlink\"></a>
</div
```

But after using evaluate method of XPath, `<a>` becomes self closed

E.g.:

```
<a onclick=\"set_cookie('Books-of-the-month_shop-now_imagetext');\" href=\"/b/books-of-the-month/_/N-2trn\" class=\"bannerlink\"/>
```

Note: This issue occurs intermittently, but my source html has

```
<a onclick="set_cookie('Books-of-the-month_shop-now_imagetext');" href="/b/books-of-the-month/_/N-2trn" class="bannerlink"></a>
```

always.

Comment: <a onclick="set_cookie('Books-of-the-month_shop-now_imagetext');" href="/b/books-of-the-month/_/N-2trn" class="bannerlink"></a> - source is like this

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my html source has anchor tag without selfclosed. Eg: (<a onclick="set_cookie('Books-of-the-month_shop-now_imagetext');" href="/b/books-of-the-month/_/N-2trn" class="bannerlink"></a>). I am using using Xpath class to scrap my div element from larger html, in scrapped html, it is like anchor tag with self closed. Eg:(<a onclick="set_cookie('Books-of-the-month_shop-now_imagetext');" href="/b/books-of-the-month/_/N-2trn" class="bannerlink"/>). I need anchor tag exactly as in source html

Comment: Why? Your link is empty (doesn't have any text), so I see no difference in anchor with closing tag and self-closing anchor

Comment: Yes it wont have any text, since it get from another api, and it will be appended at runtime by other event. this html will be rendered in ftl, since it is self closed, our UI is breaking. So needed exactly as like the source

Answer (score 0):

XPath is only concerned with looking at your data as a tree of nodes; in the tree view, `<a></a>` and `<a/>` are 100% equivalent: they correspond to the same tree view, and XPath doesn't care about the difference.

You say "`<a>` becomes self-closed", but XPath isn't doing that - XPath merely selects nodes in a tree. It's some other process that's serializing the nodes into markup, and that's where you need to look if you care about how the serialization is done. (You shouldn't care, because the two representations are equivalent, but you might care if the recipient isn't parsing the XML correctly).